# Cannot Get Haystack Tutorial Working

Tags: python, django, django-haystack

I have completed the tutorial for Haystack w/ Whoosh and re-read it about 6 times in the past few hours and cannot seem to figure out what my issue is. Basically, everything seemed to installed correctly, however when I visit the /search URL all I see is my base template without the search template (no input box/header/etc). This is my urls.py at the application level:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
url(r'^search/', include('haystack.urls')),
url(r'a/list/$', views.admin_list, name='admin_list'),
url(r'a/list/(?P<list_id>\d+)/edit/$', views.admin_edit, name='admin_edit'),
)
```

The template lives in myapp/templates/search/search.html. I have added nothing to my views.py, because the tutorial didn't go over adding anything to that file. What am I missing here?

Comment: What did you put in the template?

Comment: I used the template they used on the tutorial here:http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html. I changed a few things to be consistent with my own models, but it's largely the same.

Comment: Have you defined a `{% block content %}` in your `base.html`?

Comment: yes, I have. Still won't render. It's seems like it's not picking up the template at all. I tried to put another template in there that I know renders but that didn't work either.

Comment: I just got it to work, not entirely sure how. I might have had a small typo I didn't catch earlier in the {% block content %}. thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Was the issue resolved ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is content of the data template file ( appname_text) file , if you are keeping document =true in search_index.py file your data template should have the fields that are to be searched .

```
data template for will be something like.

{{ object.foo }}
{{ object.bar }}
```